# Validating checkout field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need some help with validating the phone field in the checkout process in WooCommerce, i.e. the phone number needs to be between 7 to 15 characters.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think this is the code:
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields )
{        
     $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['custom_attributes'] = array( "minlength" => "12" );      
     return $fields;    
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern attribute like this,

```
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['custom_attributes'] = array( "pattern" => ".{7,15}" );
```

Just paste it in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'dotpixal_override_checkout_fields' );
function dotpixal_override_checkout_fields( $fields )
{        
  $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['custom_attributes'] = array( "pattern" => ".{7,15}" );      
  return $fields;    
}
```